# How to reduce cost of the query that is executed through a Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, execution

Please see my Execution Plan(executed on SQL10.NG):

```
    Use [Reporting]

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]

    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        ---------delete existing warehouse table------------------------------
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New; 
    --------Create New Table--------------------------------------------------
    ---Weeks--------------------------------------------------------------------
    With weeks as 
    (select VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, min(VDC_day_date) as WeekCommence
    from sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
    where VDC_avail = 'T'
    group by VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year),

    ---TTWeeks------------------------------------------------------------------
    TTWeeks as

    (SELECT VDC_Cal_Year as REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] as WholeYearWeekNo, WeekCommence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no) as TermTimeWeekNo
    FROM weeks)

    ---Main---------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT    

    s.STYR_Primary_Programme AS PrimaryProgramme, 
    CASE WHEN s.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand,
    rg.REGT_Year, 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML1) AS PRPH_ML1, 
    q.GNCD_Description AS [Curriculum Area], 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML2) AS Section, 
    q.GNCD_Description AS Section_Name, 
    lEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3) AS Dept, 
    RTRIM(rg.REGT_Provision_Code) as REGT_Provision_Code, 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_Title) as PRPH_Title, 
    rg.REGT_Student_ID, STEN_Student_ID, STEN_Funding_Stream,  
    rs.REGS_Session_No, 
    RTRIM(rh.REGH_Class_Register) as Class_Register, 
    RTRIM(rh.REGH_Register_Title) as Register_Title, 
    CASE WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '1' THEN 'Sunday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '2' THEN 'Monday' 
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '3' THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '5' THEN 'Thursday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '6' THEN 'Friday' 
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '7' THEN 'Saturday' END AS Register_Day, 
    rh.[REGH_Start_Time] as StartTime, rh.[REGH_End_Time] as EndTime,
        CASE WHEN (rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%' 
    OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'FS%') 
    THEN 'FunctionalSkill' 
    WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%' THEN 'GCSE' 
    WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/D%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/E%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Addition' END AS CourseType, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') IN ('N', 'Y','X') and rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE()
    THEN rs.REGS_Duration - ISNULL(rd.REGD_Mins_Late,0) ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Poss, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') = 'Y' AND 
    rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
    rs.REGS_Duration - rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Att, 
    CASE WHEN ra.RGAT_Present = 'Y' AND rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
    rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Late, 
    rs.[REGS_Session_Date] as Session_Date, TermTimeWeekNo,
    rh.REGH_ISN, ph.PRPH_ISN, st.STUD_Surname, st.STUD_Forename_1, rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark,
    rg.REGT_start_date, rg.REGT_End_date, WeekCommence,
    STFM_LearnFAMCode,
    CASE 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'
    ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS FreeMealsIndicator,
    CASE 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=36   THEN 'Care to Learn (C2L) (EFA funded only)'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=55   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner member of a vulnerable group (EFA funded only)'  
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=56   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded discretionary bursary (EFA funded only)' 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=57   THEN 'Residential support (EFA funded only)'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=58   THEN '19+ Hardship (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'    
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=59   THEN '20+ Childcare (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'   
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=60   THEN 'Residential Access Fund (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)' 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode IN (61, 62, 63, 64, 65) THEN 'Unassigned'    
    ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS Bursary, 
    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='M' THEN 'Male'
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='F' THEN 'Female'
    END AS Gender, 
    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 32 THEN 'White - Irish'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 35 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 36 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 38 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 98 THEN 'Any Other'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 99 THEN 'Not provided'
    END AS Ethnicity,
    CASE 
    WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 1 THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 0 THEN 'No'
    END AS [Looked After Child],
    CASE 
    WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type = 'STYR' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type != 'STYR' THEN 'No'
    END AS ALS

    INTO dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New   

    FROM        
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt rg
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn rs ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rs.REGS_REGH_ISN  
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
    ON rs.REGS_Session_Date=VDC_day_date 
    INNER JOIN TTWeeks on rg.REGT_year=TTWeeks.REMSYear
    and VDC_week_no=WholeYearWeekNo and VDC_cal_year=REMSYear
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr rh ON rh.REGH_ISN = rg.REGT_REGH_ISN 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ph ON rg.REGT_Provision_Code = ph.PRPH_Code 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = PRPH_ML2 AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code AND
    STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR s ON s.STYR_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID AND s.STYR_Year = rg.REGT_Year   
    INNER JOIN (SELECT GNUC_Type, GNUC_Year, GNUC_Entity_ISN FROM sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom 
    WHERE (GNUC_Year IN ('2013', '2014', '2015'))) AS SUB1 ON rg.REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year 
    -- AND STYR_ISN = SUB1.GNUC_Entity_ISN
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     ACYR_College_Year
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR
    WHERE      (ACYR_College_Year in (2015, 2014, 2013, 2012))) AS SUB ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent st on s.STYR_Student_ID=st.STUD_Student_ID
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN AND g.GNUC_Type = 'STUD'       
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin rd ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rd.REGD_REGH_ISN AND rg.REGT_Student_ID = rd.REGD_Student_ID 
    AND rd.REGD_Session_No = rs.REGS_Session_No
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ra ON rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark = ra.RGAT_Attendance_Code 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code 
    and pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes
    WHERE      (GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2')) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code =  RTrim(PRPH_ML2) 
    COMMIT
    END

    GO
```

[image: Plan 1]

[image: Plan 2]

[image: Plan 3]

[image: Plan 4]

[image: Plan 5]

I am running into locking issues while executing the stored procedure as a job which populates data to the table so I need to know how can I improve query plan.

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: `EXEC('...') AT [SQL10.NG]`

Comment: Clear the cases ... at begining of procedure put IDs and names of STFM_LearnFAMCode and STUD_Ethnicity into temp tables and join them after on your query ... join will work a lot faster then case, as you can put index on temp table. That's first thing i would do

Comment: Use openquery to talk to the linked server databases.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I reviewed the query, I did not read it in detail.*

The query is too big. Once they reach a certain size, the SQL optimizer has problems generating valid query plans, and having "linked server tables" in the query can only exacerbate the problem. I would break that incredibly convoluted, over-complex, and generally ugly query down into steps.

First run data retrieval against the remote server or servers, storing the returned data locally, perhaps in #temp tables. (If there's a lot of data returned, build indexes on the #temp tables.) Next, join the tables to the relevant local tables.

The actual columns returned appear to contain complex business rules embedded in case statements. They might be included in the second query or, if sufficiently complex, they might call for a third query, with the results of the second stored in a second #temp table.

Smaller chunks of code can be better optimized, either by the SQL optimizer or by clever implementation. Too big is too big.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ...

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

    SELECT s.STYR_Primary_Programme AS PrimaryProgramme,
           /*....*/
           SUB1.GNUC_Type
    FROM dbo.REGTrgstudt rg
    JOIN dbo.REGSrgsessn rs ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rs.REGS_REGH_ISN
    JOIN dbo.Vdaily_calender ON rs.REGS_Session_Date = VDC_day_date
    JOIN (
        SELECT VDC_Cal_Year AS REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] AS WholeYearWeekNo, WeekCommence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no) AS TermTimeWeekNo
        FROM (
            SELECT VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, MIN(VDC_day_date) AS WeekCommence
            FROM dbo.Vdaily_calender
            WHERE VDC_avail = ''T''
            GROUP BY VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year
        ) t
    ) ON rg.REGT_year = TTWeeks.REMSYear
        AND VDC_week_no = WholeYearWeekNo
        AND VDC_cal_year = REMSYear
    JOIN dbo.REGHrghdr rh ON rh.REGH_ISN = rg.REGT_REGH_ISN
    JOIN dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ph ON rg.REGT_Provision_Code = ph.PRPH_Code
    JOIN dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = PRPH_ML2
        AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = ''M2''
    JOIN dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID
        AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code
        AND STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance
    LEFT JOIN dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year
        AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.STYRstudentYR s ON s.STYR_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID
        AND s.STYR_Year = rg.REGT_Year
    JOIN (
        SELECT GNUC_Type, GNUC_Year, GNUC_Entity_ISN
        FROM dbo.GNUCustom
        WHERE (GNUC_Year IN (''2013'', ''2014'', ''2015''))
    ) AS SUB1 ON rg.REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year
    JOIN (
        SELECT ACYR_College_Year
        FROM dbo.ACYR
        WHERE (ACYR_College_Year IN (2015, 2014, 2013, 2012))
    ) AS SUB ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year
    JOIN dbo.STUDStudent st ON s.STYR_Student_ID = st.STUD_Student_ID
    JOIN dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN
        AND g.GNUC_Type = ''STUD''
    JOIN dbo.REGDropin rd ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rd.REGD_REGH_ISN
        AND rg.REGT_Student_ID = rd.REGD_Student_ID
        AND rd.REGD_Session_No = rs.REGS_Session_No
    JOIN dbo.RGATAttendance ra ON rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark = ra.RGAT_Attendance_Code
    JOIN dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code
        AND pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance
    JOIN (
        SELECT GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description
        FROM dbo.GNCDgncodes
        WHERE (GNCD_Code_Type = ''M2'')
    ) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code = RTRIM(PRPH_ML2)'

    INSERT INTO dbo.WarehouseAttendance_TEMP
    EXEC(@sql) AT [sql10.ng]

    INSERT INTO dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New
    SELECT ...
    FROM dbo.WarehouseAttendance_TEMP

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a table variable for TTWeeks in your stored procedure. 
Doing an INNER JOIN with a Common Table expression (like in your case), calculates it every time for every record and that can affect the performance to a greater extent.

Something like this :

```
Declare @TTWeeks as table 
(
 REMSYear int
 ,WholeYearWeekNo int
 ,TermTimeWeekNo int
 ,WeekCommence datetime
 )
```

I agree with Philip Kelley's answer above. Smaller chunks of code can be better optimized compared to a huge ugly query.

Comment: where can I see this table after creating it?

Comment: Create it within your stored procedure like any other variable and then do a insert with the query that you are using in the TTWeeks CTE.
You can use a table variable like any other table. Instead of TTWeeks you should use @TTWeeks in your sql.